# ef core db-migraions create table into tablespace

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

Currently I'm evaluate using the `entity framework core migration` feature for my projects. But in our oracle database we create tables in different tablespaces.

Unfortunately I couldn't find any solution how I can configure my generated migrations to create a table in a predefined tablespace. Is there any way?

```cs
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "MyTable",
    columns: table => new
    {
        ID = table.Column<Guid>(type: "RAW(16)", nullable: false),
        SOME_ID= table.Column<Guid>(type: "RAW(16)", nullable: false)
    },
    constraints: table =>
    {
        table.PrimaryKey("PK_PATIENT", x => x.ID);
    });
```

- Where can I add the tablespace?
- Can I do any configs in my dbContext `modelBuilder`?

### Update

I ended up doing the user-approach suggested by David Browne.

Comment: Generally migrations provide only very limited access to RDBMS-specific functionality.  So normally you would either use a database-first workflow, or set the user's default tablespace.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using EF Core, have you tried setting the tablespace in the OnModelCreating method, using `modelBuilder.UseTablespace("...")`?

Comment: I only find that function in the package ```npgsql``` and that seems to be for postgreSql. We are using Oracle.

Comment: I confirm modelBuilder.UseTablespace doesn't exist for Oracle. Why ? They sleep ?